# What this Delphi's define {$WARN GARBAGE ON} means?

Tags: delphi, comments, delphi-xe, bug-tracking

I am keen on finding new conditional defines and keywords in the Delphi language which are undocumented.

Stuff like {$WARN GARBAGE ON}

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=77686

I report such stuff in Quality Central but the issue got closed and "Promoted to Internal Database".

What does this mean? Should I expect an answer to this already year and half old question?

Comment: That report is marked as Fixed in build 15.0.3714.28326. That means it's over and you should not expect the report to be updated again.

Comment: There are issues that have been open far longer than a year and a half and have been fixed eventually. Plenty older ones as well that don't get fixed. Point being: the time an issue has been open does not predict in any way whether it is dead or not...

Comment: Wow, interesting! Honestly, i have a [bad] habit of writing free-form notes past final `end.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two warnings are now [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Warning_messages_%28Delphi%29).

> **GARBAGE**: Turns on or off warnings produced when the presence of non-whitespace text is detected past the end of the final 'end.' in the program, unit, library or package
>
> **UNIT_EXPERIMENTAL**: Turns on or off all warnings about the experimental directive applied to a unit declaration.

Presumably the report was marked as fixed once the documentation was added.

Comment: Thank you! I have overlooked the docs. The original post is reformatted to sound more like a question to match your perfect answer.

Comment: I sympathise. I too find QC somewhat opaque.

Comment: The important thing here is that report actually was "Promoted to Internal Database".  That means that someone saw the original QC report and decided to add it to RAID. That's a far better resolution than QC reports that languish.  I agree that the whole process could be more transparent.

Comment: For those who don't know, RAID is the actual RAD/Delphi team's own bug tracker and it means that it is likely to get attention. QualityCentral is kind of a public "catch all bin" and RAID entries mean "probably worth doing something about".